# passing form values to uri in node and express

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, mean

this is my input.jade file

```
div
  form(action='/wiki/<topic-name>',method='post')
    div(data-role='fieldcontain')
      fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
        label(for='topicname') Topicname
          input(id='topicname',type='text',value='',placeholder='topicname',name='topicname')

    div(data-role='fieldcontain')   
      input(type='submit',value='Sign Up',data-transition='fade', data-theme='c')
```

On submit, I want it to redirect to /wiki/***topic-name***, where ***topic-name*** is entered by user in the form.

this is my routes file.

```
router.get('/input', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('content/input', { title: 'Express' });
});
router.get('/wiki/:topicname', function(req, res, next) {
    var topicname = req.params.topicname;
    //other code
});
```

How should it be done? Is there a better approach?

EDIT : If I don't want to pass the value by post, how should I proceed? (after making form method="get"). Note that I want it to redirect to specific URI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another reply pointed out, you need to remove the :topicname from the form action.

Assuming you're using Express 4, to take the topicname from the input field and redirect to /wiki/topicname:

```
//your jade form submits here
router.post('wiki/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('wiki/' + req.body.topicname);
});

//the post redirects to this page, where you do your work
router.get('wiki/:topicname', function(req, res, next) {
    var topicname = req.params.topicname;
});
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted..!

Answer (score 0):

You should use URI params only in HTTP/Get operations, look that you want to send a FORM post and your `router.get('/wiki/:topicname'` never be called because is waiting a GET and not a POST.

You should do this (code commented):

```
div
  form(action='/wiki',method='post') /*removed the uri param*/
    div(data-role='fieldcontain')
      fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
        label(for='topicname') Topicname

input(id='topicname',type='text',value='',placeholder='topicname',name='topicname')

div(data-role='fieldcontain')   
  input(type='submit',value='Sign Up',data-transition='fade', data-theme='c')
```

```
router.get('/input', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('content/input', { title: 'Express' });
});
router.post('/wiki', function(req, res, next) { // now route is getting POST
    var topicname = req.body.topicname; // get params from body
    //other code
});
```

Comment: and how would that redirect me to /wiki/topic-name, from the value passed via get ?